# MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 9009

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vtk

When I try to build VTK on VS 2010, I get this error  `error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 9009.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 151   6   vtkhdf5`

Before this, I build QT successfully from VS command prompt.
My opinion is that there's something wrong with the paths of directories.
I've been searching on the internet for a while but couldn't find a way to fix.

Comment: Do you get any other errors?  I would expect something more...

Comment: `cmd` exit code of `9009` means `'something' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`, where `something` (the single quoted text) vary

Comment: Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run->Verbosity  to Diagnostic, might help

Answer (score 21):

You should first check the **output window** message of your VS2010 rather than just **error list window**.

After that, you can find some hint on your errors, like missing executable files or something like that. Errors may vary, but if your case is - exe file missing, then go to project properties:

> Project(Your project name) -> Properties -> Configuration Properties
>   -> VC++ Directories -> Executable Directories

, add the folder of your missing exe.