# cmd.exe exited with code 9009

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to compile XNABasics project in visual studio from this repository 
https://code.google.com/p/kinect4bag/

But it gives me a error named:

> Error 1   error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 9009. C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets  151 6   CGePhysics

and when i double click it redirects me to the page given below, i have checked the project properties does not have anything in custom build step and custom build tool area.

[image]

Comment: It uses a custom build tool, SWIG.  Did you install it?  Does compiling CGePhysics.i work?

Comment: I installed SWIG and added it to the environment variables but it still shows the same error. compiling CGePhysics dosen't work, any other ideas ?

Comment: Sorry, i was compiling CGEPhysics.i using visual studio. now i am compiling in command line using SWIG , it gives me a error saying  Error: Unable to find 'arrays_csharp.i'..

Comment: It's really hard to read your bitmap of text, could you paste text instead of a bitmap? And it's impossible to tell where line 151 is without *all* the text.

Answer (score 3):

Just came across this thread now.

I had the exact same error. In my case, the swig.exe path that my project was looking for was wrong. My issue was fixed once i made sure the SWIG package was in the same path that my Project Properties' Macro was looking.

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem it was due to missing Direct X executable paths in the property manager. As suggested at this Stack Overflow thread: [MSB6006: “cmd.exe” exited with code 9009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069464/msb6006-cmd-exe-exited-with-code-9009)

Upon inspecting my build log I found that

```
'fxc' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

which brought me to this solution: ['fxc.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command](http://cuda-experience.blogspot.com/2011/03/fxcexe-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or.html)

I went into my property manager to Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user and added the proper DirectX SDK paths to Executables, Include, and Library (C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK\Utilities\bin\x64, C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK\Include, C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK\Lib\x86 respectively)

Answer (score 0):

This error shows that execution of a command in command line environment fails. You should view output logs(e.g., view->output in visual studio) and find this error. For example, following log illustrated that windows command cannot recognize 'make' syntax. So, I replaced it with 'nmake' and set PATH variable for it.

```
2>  'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

2>  operable program or batch file.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(170,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 9009.